# Picasso on custom ListView appear out of memory

Tags: listview, picasso

I'm using the picasso to load the pictures from assets floder which have about 900 pictures. But when I slided the ListView,the logcat would appear out of memory.

My custom listrow places_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

My custom Adapter getView code

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder=null;
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        holder.mImageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_test);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    Picasso.with(mContext).load("file:///android_asset/picture/" + mPictureNames.get(position)).resize(200,200).into(holder.mImageView);


  //  holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(getPicture(position));

    return convertView;
}
```